# Create a new master

Tags: git

I have imported my svn repository to git. My current branch for development is **branch1** and I would like to rename the one in **master**. Can I remove current master branch(with very old info) painless and create a new remote branch from branch1 with name master?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want really want to get rid of legacy history? You might regret it some time later, as it can be useful to refer to previous logs and bug fixes.

Comment: I think it makes sense but the master is very old and our code has been changed a lot in another branch and team too so history from master is useless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you no longer need the information in `master`, you could easily get rid of it:

```
git branch -D master
```

Once `master` is gone, you could rename `branch1` to be the new `master`:

```
git branch -m branch1 master
```

If you are a bit uncertain whether you might need the information held in `master` one day, you could achieve this by renaming `master` to `old_master` before renaming `branch1` to `master`:

```
git branch -m master old_master
git branch -m branch1 master
```